# Relation between binomial distribution and multinomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, joint-distribution

I am learning multinomial distribution.

Given that
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}{\text{a bowl of chips are labelled }}i{\text{ }}\left( {i = 1, \cdots ,k} \right)\\{\theta _i} = {\text{proportion of chip }}i{\text{ }}\left( {{\text{prob of getting chip }}i{\text{ in 1 draw}}} \right)\\{\text{draw }}n{\text{ chips from the bowl and observe their labels }}\left\{ {{s_1}, \cdots ,{s_n}} \right\}\\{X_i} \equiv {\text{num of lable }}i{\text{ in }}\left\{ {{s_1}, \cdots ,{s_n}} \right\} \equiv \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{I_{\left\{ i \right\}}}\left( {{s_j}} \right)} \end{array} \right.$$

Then we know
$$\left( {{X_1},{X_2}, \cdots ,{X_k}} \right)\sim{\text{Multinomial}}\left( {n,{\theta _1},{\theta _2}, \cdots ,{\theta _k}} \right)$$

---

Is it true that? ::
$${X_i}\sim Binomial\left( {n,{\theta _i}} \right) \quad \forall {X_i}$$

---

Is the converse also ture? ie::

$$\begin{array}{l}
if:{X_i}\sim Bin\left( {n,{\theta _i}} \right)\\
then:\left( {{X_1},{X_2}, \cdots ,{X_k}} \right)\sim {\text{Multinomial}}\left( {n,{\theta _1},{\theta _2}, \cdots ,{\theta _k}} \right){\text{ }}\\
\left( {{\text{the joint distribution of }}\left( {{X_1},{X_2}, \cdots ,{X_k}} \right){\text{ is multinomial}}} \right)
\end{array}$$

---

For the 1st question, I think its true, according to the definition of binomial distribution.

For the 2nd question, I am not sure whether we need some conditions like iid or not.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).